# Remove duplicate class instances based on object identity

Tags: swift, collections, duplicates

I'm writing a component for caching instances of classes. The classes are not per se `Comparable`, `Hashable` or `Equatable`. If they were, the semantics of the respective operations would not necessarily serve our purposes, so let's pretent we can not use those protocols.

Objects can be cached w.r.t. multiple keys. So when asking the cache for a list of all cached objects, I need to remove duplicates from the value set of the underlying dictionary -- with respect to *object identity*.

Obviously, this does the job:

```
var result: [C] = []
for c in dict.values {
    if !result.contains(where: { (rc: C) in rc === c }) {
        result.append(c)
    }
}
return result
```

However, this has quadratic runtime behaviour. Compared to linearithmic or expected linear behaviour that are easy to get when using abovementioned protocols (using set implementations), this is bad.

So how can we efficiently remove duplicates w.r.t. object identity from a Swift collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can wrap our objects into something that *is* `Hashable` and `Comparable`:

```
struct ClassWrap<T: AnyObject>: Hashable, Comparable {
    var value: T

    var hashValue: Int {
        return ObjectIdentifier(self.value).hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: ClassWrap, rhs: ClassWrap) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value === rhs.value
    }

    static func <(lhs: ClassWrap<T>, rhs: ClassWrap<T>) -> Bool {
        return ObjectIdentifier(lhs.value) < ObjectIdentifier(rhs.value)
    }
}
```

Now, any regular `Set` implementation or otherwise unique-fying operation should do the job.